# Move virtualized system to create dual boot

Tags: windows, virtualbox, dual-boot, virtual-machine

I'm using VirtualBox on Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows XP guest system. I also have an empty NTFS partition on my hard drive. Is there any way I could "move" my Windows XP to that partition and make it bootable to enable dual-boot? I wouldn't complain if it was still available to launch from VirtualBox (but that's not neccessary).

Any way to do this??

Answer (score 1):

While theoretically possibly, I don't know if it would be worth the effort to fix all of the hardware, driver, and related issues you will encounter if you copy the disk image of your VM to an actual partition, create the proper boot-loader configuration, etc. It would probably be faster to install Windows fresh and copy over anything from one to the other, or use a shared disk between the VM and the real system.

I have seen a system that was setup to dual boot Windows XP and Ubuntu Linux, where the Ubuntu Linux OS had a virtualization app (VMplayer, maybe? I forget) that could run the Windows OS as a VM. This was about 10-12 years ago, was a huge kluge, and was more to show off the novelty than do anything useful...it was slow and klunky.

Of course OS X and VMware Fusion do this beautifully, but that is a commercial privately developed and supported application.

In both cases, the virtualization of the second OS comes AFTER the dual boot configuration is setup and working. You would be going the other way, which would require a lot more effort. If you want a quick fix, probably not worth the effort. If you are simply curious and want to hack away at the problem to make it work, it would be a cool project that I would enjoy watching progress.